# React.forwardRef Causes Error with Styled Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, styled-components, forward-reference

I am running React 16.3.1 and Styled Components 3.2.5 currently and am hitting an issue trying to use React.forwardRef.

I have an Input component that is comprised of a wrapper div that holds the label and input field. However, I want to be able to forward a ref directly to the input field and not have to traverse to it via the primary wrapping div.

```
const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Label htmlFor={props.id} required={props.required}>
      {props.label}
    </Label>

    <InputField
      id={props.id}
      ...
    />
  </Wrapper>
));
```

That is a simplified version of my component. However, this creates the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: [object Object]
```

Maybe upgrading Styled Components to v4 would help? But is there any solution before upgrading that I haven't found yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [related issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2106), there is blocking [React Redux issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/914) that is expected to be closed with [this PR](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/pull/1000).

A workaround is to use an approach that was used before React 16.3 `forwardRef` and use custom prop instead of `ref` to forward refs:

```
const Input = ({forwardRef, ...props}) => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Label htmlFor={props.id} required={props.required}>
      {props.label}
    </Label>

    <InputField
      ref={forwardRef}
      id={props.id}
      ...
    />
  </Wrapper>
));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to modify your answer slightly since my version of Styled Components still expected ìnnerRef` as opposed to `ref`.  Otherwise, I was able to make this work.

Answer (score -3):

Why `<Wrapper {...rest}>`?

I thing pass ref to Wrapper is a correct way:

```
<Wrapper ref={ref}>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a carry over from old code. Unrelated. But I don't want to put the ref on the Wrapper. I would need it on the Input field.